# Send-MailMessage body now displaying all data of For loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a batch script that has a FOR loop and a PS script to send email.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,7" %%i in ('autorep -m ALL ^| findstr /v "Machine____Online”’) do set machine_name=%%i & set STATUS=%%j

powershell
-Command Send-MailMessage
-SmtpServer smtp.something.com
-To someone@something.com
-From someone@something.com
-Subject
'Agent Status'
-Body
‘%machine_name%, %STATUS%’
```

But when I run this script, I only receive the first line of the output of the for loop. Anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried separating the script into a batch script and a PS script. Run the batch script to direct the output into a text file and then run the ps script to process that file but it’s not working.

Comment: Any reason this must be a batch script?  You can easily do this 100% in PowerShell, which would be easier as well.

Comment: My organisation doesn’t  allow me to run .ps1 ext files

Comment: As aside, replace all those curly quotes (`”’`) with straight ones